# Treeview field type?

Tags: fields, fieldtype

I need users to select certain locations from a (possibly) tree view UI. The tree view might contain something like a list of states, with each state with a list of counties, with each county with a list of ... and so on.

Later on, I need to be able to display Channel entries wherein certain items in the tree view were selected. For example, display all Channel entries where "City 1" or "City 18" were selected.

Is there a EE or addon FT solution for this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the issue is actually around Cities, States, Countries, then you may want to take a look at [REEgion Select](http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/reegion-select), a third party add-on by @Derek Hogue who answers a number of questions here.

If your issue is really more about being able to base one field of the selection of another, than take a look at [Query Field](http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/query-field). I haven't used it, yet, but do have a project that I've been looking at it for.

Though for your final display issue, I think you may want to either use a filtering system, like [Isotope](http://isotope.metafizzy.co)—a javascript filtering method, a tagging system, either Solspace [Tag](http://www.solspace.com/software/detail/tag/) or DevDemon's [Tagger](http://www.devdemon.com/tagger/). Obviously you could use custom queries as well, but I think one of the above maybe an easier approach. Tagger is free and if you don't need all the features of Solspace's module is a nice way to go.

For Treeview itself, there is no specific add-on or fieldtype that I've heard of, but I'd assume mainly because Treeview is about clustering or  hierarchical data. Generally speaking,  hierarchical groupings have been category based, meaning you create your list and sublist and subsets of data manually and kind of hope things don't change to much. You can still do this with a combination of categories, subcategories, tags/keywords, and maybe add some [javascript](http://jquery.bassistance.de/treeview/demo/).

Distributive classification, tagging, can be more flexible and responsive to your needs, while still allowing for flexible filtering of data. In terms of data entry, I think tags are probably easier, or a mixture of tags and categories (unless you are literally dealing with locations*).

If you are actually dealing with locations, than I'd recommend something that does assistive auto-completes. Like just allow the user to enter a postal code, then recommend city, state, region, country from that, but allow them to be modifiable.

Comment: My issue does revolve around geographic regions so I'll take a look at REEgion Select. I'll see if the addon will work for my scenario (I need users to be able to easily select multiple nodes, etc.). Query Field seems like it'll give me a "drill down" capability, which could be useful for another section of the project I'm working on. You've provided with a bunch of other information here. I'll have to go over them. Thanks. Lots to research.

Comment: Good luck, let me know what works or doesn't work for you.